# Windows Phone 8.1 Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8.1, mstest

I have a Windows 8.1 Universal application that I have run into an issue with unit testing.  I am using MSTest.  I have a test that needs to make sure that an exception is thrown.  The test is pretty simple, if a null value if passed in, it fails.  The exception thrown should be `ArgumentNullException`. However, I am having trouble finding the correct way for this to pass.  I tried using `ExpectedExpection` as an attribute but I was unable to find a reference that would work with a Windows Phone unit test project. I did find `Assert.ThrowsException` but was not able to find any information on how to use it.

What is the best way to make sure that this exception is being thrown and for the test to pass if it does get thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSTest  you usually use `ExpectedException` like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DoWhatEverThrowsAnArgumentNullException();
    }
```

If you don't like it that way then you can look at this project on GitHub: [MSTestExtensions](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/MSTestExtensions)